# How to unzip a zipped folder which contains TAR files which contain zipped files, each containing CSV file, in Data Factory?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, unzip, blobstorage, data-ingestion

I am currently learning how to use Azure Data Factory. I try to do a data ingestion and transformation that I did in a Python script. Now I try to do the same on Data Factory as it is supposed to be easier.

I have a zipped folder. It contains Tar files. Each file contains zipped cvs file. By ingesting csv file directly to a blob it would be easy of course but if I have to automate the reception of such a zipped folder how would I be able to load the csv in a database if I even can't figure out how to unzip, detar and unzip again? In this cas I use climate data from a real case study... I you have any idea how to handle this problem I would appreciate! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support), adf blob storage dataset only supports below compression type:

[image]

Tar format is not supported by adf naturally. However,you could follow the solution which is mentioned in the same document, using Azure Function to [extract the contents of a tar file](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/SamplesV2/UntarAzureFilesWithAzureFunction) or build this functionality using a custom dotnet activity. Considering your slightly complicated situation, I suggest you using custom activity.